# Configuracão .htacess - Página de Erro dinamica

Tags: javascript, html, htaccess

Gostaria de saber se é possivel gerar uma pagina de erro dinamica a partir de  parametros passados para uma pagina html e pegar esses parametros atraves de um codigo javascript? Ou de qualquer outra forma que não precise criar uma pagina para cada erro.

Exemplo:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.html?400
ErrorDocument 401 /error.html?401
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html?403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html?404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html?500
```

Comment: tenta se isso resolve
Options -Indexes, ai voce só precisa ter uma maneira de pegar com javascript e fazer a malandragem...

ErrorDocument 403 /pasta/403.html?id=403
ErrorDocument 404 /pasta/404.html?id=404

Answer (score 0):

Isso é bem simples, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
RewriteRule ^403.php$ erros.php?tipo=403 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^404.php$ erros.php?tipo=404 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
RewriteRule ^500.php$ erros.php?tipo=500 [L,QSA]
```

E por aí vai..

Os arquivos 404.php , 500.php , etc não precisam existir fisicamente. O .htaccess vai tratar eles de forma automática e redirecionar como você quer.

No arquivo erros.php (por exemplo), você trata o tipo de erro com $_GET['tipo'] e emite a mensagem pretendida.

[Este artigo](https://www.homehost.com.br/blog/como-customizar-paginas-de-erro-404-e-500-no-seu-site/) explica um pouco mais sobre como trabalhar com as paginas de erro no servidor.